# Help with PDAL install on windows

Tags: windows, point-cloud

I am trying to install PDAL from github according to the following instructions:

```
Clone into a source directory: git clone https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL PDAL
Make a build directory: mkdir PDAL-build
Enter the build directory: cd PDAL-build
Run CMake to find dependencies: cmake ../PDAL
Or, see https://github.com/PDAL/PDAL/blob/master/cmake/examples/pramsey-config.sh
If dependencies are not found, manually set them: ccmake ../PDAL
Once CMake has found all dependencies, run the build: make all
And install the artifacts: make install
```

and I am kind of stuck. I don't really understand how the cmake prosses works. I have cmake and i do exactly what it says but I get a whole page of errors shown in the image. Anyone can help me or explain what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: The whole point of installing PDAL is to use pgpointcloud (https://github.com/pgpointcloud/pointcloud)

Comment: The environment is not set for the C compiler as written in the error message. Which C compiler did you install? May be there is a bat file to set up the environment for it (setenv.bat or similar).

Comment: I don't think this is really specific to PDAL or GIS generally. Its a "how do I set up my development environment", which would apply to any cmake build. Probably the GUI will help you - see http://www.cmake.org/runningcmake/

Comment: pgpointcloud support is available in the OSGeo4W64 Windows build http://www.pdal.io/download.html#binaries

Comment: I finally managed to do it but still I don't get all the drivers for pgpointcloud. I tried both methods for Windows. from OSGeo4W64 and from building from the source. But should I get all the drivers with the OSGeo4W64? Because using pdal --drivers I miss filters.cache etc

Comment: filters.cache is no longer a valid filter for PDAL. OSGeo4W64 should have working pgpointcloud support. Please report on the mailing list if you have trouble.

Comment: I realised that after a lot of time. Indeed better documentation could help.